# Remove the hash in page URL and stop the page from scrolling to anchor hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two pages, index.html and result.html. On index.html, I have some anchors in the navigation where when they're clicked, they add a hash to my page Url and it changes the Url to this, example:

```
https://example.com/index.html?SessionGuid=0edc696e-6f58-4d54-92c9-3753f5db57ae#someAnchor
```

In this page, there's a form with a submit button, when the submit button is clicked the form values are being sent over to result.html. And that creates a jumping to the middle of the page instead of showing the top of the page.

This is how my result.html page Url looks like:

```
https://example.com/result.html?SessionGuid=0edc696e-6f58-4d54-92c9-3753f5db57ae#someAnchor
```

So, I used this method to remove the hash on my result.html:

```
history.replaceState('', document.title, window.location.origin + window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
```

This works perfectly in Chrome, the hash is being removed and the page is staying at the top. In FireFox though, the hash is being removed but the page is still scrolling to the hash location.

What is the difference between FF and Chrome when it comes to this behavior? Is there a cross-browser solution to fix this? Is it the location where the script is located? I am open to either jQuery or pure JS. Also open to remove the hash before the form is summited in index.html. Whichever that is cross-browser compatible.

Comment: Can't you just alter the code that generates the redirect and remove any semblance of the hash in the URL??

Comment: That part is handled by the backend system and I only have access to front-end.

Comment: Short answer is no. Long answer is nooooooooooooooooooooooo.

Comment: Lol.. why not? I am able to remove the hash and stop the scrolling with document.location.hash = ''; but the hash sign is still staying in the Url which is not a big deal